# Проверка данных на наличие firebase flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Я новичок и столкнулся с проблемой. Суть такая: пользователь вводит удобную для него дату и время, эта информация заносится в Cloud Firebase. При занесении инфы должна выполняться проверка; есть такая запись с числом и датой или нет, если есть, то должно вылезти диалоговое окно с соответствующей информацией. Я пробовал проверить это с помощью 'where()', не получилось. Не нашел ничего толкового в официальной документации. Есть какое-то решение в интернете, но оно мне не помогло( Вид Firebase такой: есть коллекция users, там пользователи и у каждого пользователя есть информация(дата, время, id).

```
  isdata(date){
final ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').orderBy('date');
if(year == ref){
  Timer.run(() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) =>
          AlertDialog(
            title: Text("занято"),
          ),
    );
  });
}
```

написал такую функцию для проверки даты. Не работает. Спасибо!)

Answer (score 0):

Я все-таки нашел способ, хоть он и весьма примитивный, но работает исправно.

Написал функцию для проверки:

```
isdata(date){
//создаем пустой список
var dates=[];
//инициализируем нашу базу данных
var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
await db.collection("users").get().then((event) {
//получаем данные date и заносим их в список
    for (var doc in event.docs) {
      dates.add(doc.get('date'));
//проверяем на наличие
    if (date.contains(date)==true){
     print('занято');
      }
    }
  }
}
```